# How to count the data of nested model relationship

Tags: laravel

h_d_s table is the health demographic, it has column name hd which list the hd of the respondents such as Physical Condition, Ages, Sexes, etc.

h_d_s table has many categoriy this is the h_d_categories table, these are the categories of each hd, for Ages hd it has categories like 13 Below, 14 above etc.

the h_d_categories belongs to h_d_category_respondents table that has respondent_id and hd_category_id which indicates the hd_category of the respondent.

I want to display in a table the list of hd_categories and count the number of respondents having those category.

[image]

in this picture, the 85 and 89 is the list of ALL the respondends id

I want to replace the respondent id to the total number of respondent having those hd category